# How to make search query on Blogger JSON Feed API

Tags: json, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views, google-blogger-api

I want to search my posts on blogger by using blogger feed JSON API. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

**To search using blogger V3 API:**
100% WORKING

Searches for a post that matches the given query terms. [Try it now](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/search#try-it)
[image]

**Read more:**
https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/search

[image]

**Eg api:**
[https://blogger.googleapis.com/v3/blogs/{BLOG](https://blogger.googleapis.com/v3/blogs/%7BBLOG) ID}/posts/search?q=salem&key={API KEY}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search your posts with blogger JSON feed API, you can do that with use below link.
Write your blog name and write your search word with `q` parameter. (ex: `q=word`).

For posts:
`blogname.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=json&max-results=500&q=word`

For Pages: `blogname.blogspot.com/feeds/pages/default?alt=json&max-results=500&q=word`